# Finding Heading number of selection as well as preceding Heading numbers

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to get the Heading number, and all preceeding Heading Level numbers of a selection in word VBA simply through the selection of text. For example:

## 10.1

### 10.1.1

10.1.1.1

"This is my text"

I want to be able to select "This is my text" and write each preceeding Heading level (i.e. 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1, 10.1) into an array so that I can write each value into a separate cell in Excel.

I've come up with a solution that uses.

```
oWord.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious).Select
```

to obtain the text "10.1.1.1", however I then drop into various loops that loop through EACH previous Heading to determine the Heading Level and obtain their number, as shown below.

```
HeadingSearch4:

                    If oWord.Selection.Style = "Heading 4" Then
                            Do
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                                oWord.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious).Select
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                            Loop Until prevHeading = "Heading 3"
                        GoTo HeadingSearch3
                    End If

HeadingSearch3:

                    If oWord.Selection.Style = "Heading 3" Then
                        lgHeading3num = oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
                            Do
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                                oWord.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious).Select
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                            Loop Until prevHeading = "Heading 2"
                        GoTo HeadingSearch2
                    End If
HeadingSearch2:
                    If oWord.Selection.Style = "Heading 2" Then
                        lgHeading2num = oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
                            Do
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                                oWord.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, 
wdGoToPrevious).Select
                                prevHeading = oWord.Selection.Style
                            Loop Until prevHeading = "Heading 1"
                        GoTo HeadingSearch1
                    End If
HeadingSearch1:
                    If oWord.Selection.Style = "Heading 1" Then
                        lgHeading1num = "Section " & oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
                    End If
```

Obviously, this is taking a MASSIVE amount of time when I get a few levels deep down the outline (i.e. 10.10.5.5) since it has to loop through EVERY previous Heading, regardless of Heading Level.

My question is.... is there any easier way to use.

```
oWord.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious).Select
```

to go to the previous Heading Level? For example if my text is at under "10.1.5", can I go straight to "10.1" without looping through the rest of the preceding Heading 3's? Or is there a property of Selection that I'm missing? I couldn't find a way to use "wdGoToPrevious" to go the next highest Heading Level. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If styles are being used you can use Range. (or Selection.)Find to search a specific style, going backwards (or forwards).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use pseudo-code simply because I don't have time to fully test this in Word.

I am going to tackle your problem in a different way.

- A significant point is not to use `Selection` - the selection can
  change based on code or user input and you may not realise it.
- I will use the built-in Paragraphs collection, in the context of the Whole Document range (let's call it `wdAllDocRange` for the sake of my pseudo-code).

I originally considered using a Turing-tape style of process. But the code below identified an easier approach.

```
Dim counter as Long ' set up the navigation
Dim coll as Collection
Counter = 1 ' start at the beginning
While counter < wdAllDocRange.Paragraphs.Count ' error check - we have reached the end of file
    GetCurrentLevel wdAllDocRange.Paragraphs(counter) 'Code here to get current level
    if a Heading
        if a new level then
            coll.add currentlevel
        else if same level then
            coll.replace lastlevel with currentlevel number
        else if a previous level then
            coll.removelevels until at the right level then set level number
    else
        output coll and text into the array for further use
    endif
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

The code above uses an old fashioned loop (because I was thinking of moving back and forth through the range), but you could actually enclose all the main code in a `for-each` loop

```
Dim coll as Collection
Dim para as Paragraph
For Each para in wdAllDocRange.Paragraphs 
    GetCurrentLevel para 'Code here to get current level
    if a Heading
        if a new level then
            coll.add currentlevel
        else if same level then
            coll.replace lastlevel with currentlevel number
        else if a previous level then
            coll.removelevels until at the right level then set level number
    else
        output coll and text into the array for further use
    endif
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, j As Long, StrOut As String
Set Rng = Selection.Range: j = 10
Do While Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.Style <> "Heading 1"
  If InStr(Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.Style, "Heading") <> 0 Then
    i = CLng(Split(Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.Style, " ")(1))
    If i < j Then
      j = i
      StrOut = Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.ListFormat.ListString & ", " & StrOut
    End If
  End If
  Rng.Start = Rng.Start - 1
  Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
Loop
StrOut = Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.ListFormat.ListString & ", " & StrOut
MsgBox StrOut
End Sub
```